# NestJS 9.4.0 crashes while creating Fastify app

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, throttling, nestjs-passport, nestjs-fastify

I installed Throttler for NestJS 9.4.0 application to secure it but it gives me an error when i use NestFastify anyone know how it should look like correctly? A needs to use Fastify for subsequent security such as CSRF. I've been struggling with solving this problem for a long time, I even decided to ask on ChatGPT and it suggests that everything is fine. I will add that the error only appears after entering the appropriate route.

**Works Main Code:**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get<string>('PORT', '');

  // Throttler - Protection
  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Main Code not working:**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get<string>('PORT', '');

  // Throttler - Protection
  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

**App Module Code:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      ignoreEnvFile: !!process.env.CI,
      envFilePath: join(__dirname, '..', '.env'),
      validationSchema: envSchema,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
    }),
    // Throttler - Protection
    ThrottlerModule.forRoot({
      ttl: Number(process.env.THROTTLER_TTL),
      limit: Number(process.env.THROTTLER_LIMIT),
      storage: {
        store: 'redis',
        options: {
          url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`,
        },
      },
    }),
    PassportModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        defaultStrategy: configService.get('jwt.defaultStrategy'),
      }),
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Error:**

```
[Nest] 26552  - 01.05.2023, 22:48:28   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] res.setHeader is not a function
TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
    at FacebookStrategy.strategy.redirect (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:331:13)
    at stored (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:285:14)
    at NullStore.store (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\state\null.js:5:3)
    at FacebookStrategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:297:28)
    at FacebookStrategy.Strategy.authenticate (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:84:41)
    at attempt (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:369:16)
    at authenticate (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:370:7)
    at H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:97:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\passport\dist\auth.guard.js:89:83
```

Comment: looks like you're using a express-supported only package like `passport`.

Comment: so what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport doesn't *always* work well with Fastify, especially with the OAuth specific strategies. To get around this, you can decorator the `FastifyReply` and `FastifyRequest` objects with methods and properties to make passport work. The following snippet can be used to modify and decorator the objects accordingly:

```js
const fastifyInstance: FastifyInstance = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance()
  fastifyInstance
    .addHook('onRequest', async (req, res) => {
      req.socket['encrypted'] = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    })
    .decorateReply('setHeader', function (name: string, value: unknown) {
      this.header(name, value)
    })
    .decorateReply('end', function () {
      this.send('')
    })
```

Add this to your `main.ts` before you call `app.listen()` and it should work

Comment: but it doesn't see fastify instance for me

Comment: [It's a type from the fastify package](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/types/instance.d.ts#L91)